# Getting error when editing web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I made a page layout in SP 2013, and then added a content query web part and then when I try to edit the web part settings, I get this error

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=95EF7F44FE8255B0!23870&authkey=!ADhD5dddVEHRINw&ithint=file%2ctxt

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an attempt to answer (I just don't have the rep to simply post a comment to your question).

Can you replace the link that you posted above with a screen shot of what the error looked like or maybe use the snipping tool. The link provided doesn't show the error just a huge log of information.

Comment: The error is near the bottom